# idea не видит библиотеку из pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jar

Нужно добавить библиотеку Autoit на java https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.openkeyword/autoit/0.2.44
Я добавил зависимость в pom.xml
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но idea, не видит библиотеку.
Тогда я добавил к idea jar файл, библиотека появилась в external libraries но результат тот же, она не импортируется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вас красное подчёркивание в конце названия пакета в импорте не смущает? После добавления Maven зависимости в проект его (проект) нужно обновить (по крайней мере в Eclipse так). После обновления проекта в импорте, после добавления точки должно показываться автозавершение кода с доступными классами и завершите строку точкой с запятой. Либо для импорта всех членов пакета после точки добавьте звёздочку (asterics) - `import de.autokeyword.*;`